# try to prove that my question was not clear

Tags: discussion

my question [Try to prove zenith shadow addition to shadow of 1 height of object, to get Asr prayer time's shadow](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17723/prove-zenith-shadow-addition-to-shadow-of-1-height-of-object-to-get-asr-prayer) is put on hold as unclear. try to prove that it was unclear, even its first edition. i feel like this 3 moderators are bullying me for some reason. i think my question was perfectly clear. concretely what place and why was unclear there? are not you ashamed? do not you fear of jahannam?!

read word by word from beginning and show in which place it becomes unclear

Comment: Not really, it is hard to understand what is it that your after in asking your question, I have an idea but your question does not make it clear at all. Your just being over defensive rather than being open to criticism and feedback

Comment: @aboudi read word by word from beginning and show in which place it becomes unclear

Comment: I have edited your question, the parts which I removed are the parts that don't make sense at all.

Comment: Lol no one gets bullied here!

Comment: @Casanova what do you mean?

Comment: You said 3 moderators were bullying you

Comment: How come 3 mods are bullying you if one of the 3 we have isn't even active since Allah knows when?

Comment: @Medi1Saif maybe you mean other moderators, i say about these who voted on my question.

Comment: Those who voted are not necessary mods as we are a community moderated "platform" a thing you should know as you seem to be here on SE network at least as long as I'm!

Comment: @Medi1Saif i named them "moderators" by their capability and functions.

Comment: Well you have the same privileges https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges as a >500 rep user!

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, A good starting point is to read the [theory of moderation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/) article, as this is the basis of how Stack Exchange is moderated ... by the community, you and I included. To assume that three moderators are bullying any user for that matter would definitely get noticed by other moderators. We are our own moderators, and I can tell you from my personal experience when I cast votes that I have not seen any indication of voting against any specific user.

Secondly, the effort put forth by the moderators is huge, and to be commended, as they are doing so off their own personal time with no reward other than what Allah has in store for them. If you do not agree with their opinion:

1. Be an active participant and cast your own vote. You can contribute since you have over 500 points and can review posts from new users.
2. Ask for their rationale in a non-confrontational manner. They will most likely have a valid reason that is escaping you.

Thirdly, from my own personal experience, I can tell you that it is best to have a positive view of the moderators feedback. It will help you get your contributions to be more valuable. My first attempt at answering a question was that of [Rebecca's](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/17163/rebecca-j-stones) on [what the modern-day applicability of "teach your children ... horse riding"](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35753/) is. My response was critiqued by [Medi1Saif](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/13438/medi1saif) due to its lack of substance to address the question, which I had put some effort in forming it. His comments helped me get an initial understanding of how online Q&A environments work, and it is beneficial for me till now. 'Umar ibn al-Khattāb used to say: "May Allah be merciful to the one who gifts me with my shortcomings (Arabic: رحم الله امرأً أهدى إلي عيوبي). Note that 'Umar considered this a gift.

Finally, I could not understand your question initially, in spite of reading it multiple times. I applaud [Uma](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/20218/uma) for understanding the question, and providing an answer. Reading Uma's answer made me understand the question.

Please take this as positive feedback to assist us (first) and you (second) to be helpful to others who want to learn about Islam, and be positive contributors to the community, in and out of SE. The more contributors we have, the better. I am learning a lot by attempting to answer questions. "The last of it is musk. So for this let the competitors compete."

Comment: This remainds of the athar: : إذا بلغك عن أخيك الشيء تنكره فالتمس له عذرا واحدا إلى سبعين عذرا، فإن أصبته، وإلا، قل لعل له عذرا لا أعرفه.

Comment: read word by word from beginning and show in which place it becomes unclear

Answer (score 2):

I was the first to vote to close as *unclear what you're asking*.  I explained why in the comments at the time (which you responded to).  These comments are now deleted, as the question has been edited, and they're no longer needed.

**What's the question?** It was difficult to find the actual question in the text.  It was like trying to find Wally in a [Where's Wally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where%27s_Wally%3F) cartoon.  Presumably it's in there somewhere, but it requires a lot of searching.

This was what I saw when I voted to close:

> *Title*: Prove zenith shadow addition to shadow of 1 height of object, to get Asr prayer time's shadow
>
> *Body*: Scholars say zenith shadow length of object should be added to 1 height of the object to get Asr time's shadow length, but in the texts of hadiths' it is only 1 height of object, without addition of its zenith shadow length. I cannot accept this think of scholars, because 1 object height should mean 1 object height, without additions, in languages. Please say me whether also Shia scholars make this zenith shadow addition. And please try to prove the think, (for example, with documents, natural speech examples in Arabic language), trying to show that shadow length as 1 object height does not mean shadow length as 1 object height in Arabic language.

In an effort to identify the question, I asked you if this was the question "Please say me whether also Shia scholars make this zenith shadow addition."  You said it wasn't.

I subsequently made a second guess in the comments as to what the question was (which wasn't clarified).  I also pointed out the language problems (which weren't fixed).

---

**My motivation**: I simply saw the unanswered question, and intended to improve the writing (which I do to zillions of questions).  However, I found I was incapable of doing so because I couldn't figure out what the question was.

Voting to close is aimed to prompt the OP (or others) into editing the question (if possible).  In the comments I directly suggested editing the question, and I can retract the close vote once the question is clear.  This editing to have been achieved now.

Comment: you need not to search it, it is in title

Comment: i had not intention to get answer. they could not answer because they could not prove. (not because it was unclear). now my question is edited and it has got an answer, not because it has become clear, but because it has stopped to require proof. (this is edition of question that was written 2017-06-19 05:18:23Z).

Comment: read word by word from beginning and show in which place it becomes unclear